# Is there a documentation that gives information on different parameters/values that can be passed to QueryRequest in RallyRestAPI?

Tags: rally

I want to develop an application that can integrate with rally, hence I got to know about java-tool-kit rally rest api. So that for example, I can query rally to get information about a feature, list of user stories in that feature, owner of that feature etc.. or List of fields we can fetch for our request on userstory, defect, Feature etc

```
        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("PortfolioItem_Feature");
        queryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Feature"));
        queryRequest.setLimit(1000);
        queryRequest.setScopedDown(true);
```

In above code, if I want to look for Feature and US in that feature, a documentation for such might be of great help.